# Taboo Script or Undesired Note

Tags: r

I  included in my package the following scripts;

```
foo  <- function(X){ Y <-substitute(X);cat(Y)}




 fooo <-function(){
  foo(aaa)
}
```

Then  `R cmd check` said the undesired `note`:

> > checking R code for possible problems ... NOTE   fooo: no visible binding for global variable 'aaa'

How to remove this note or I have to change the definition of `foo()`?

---

**Details**

The `foo` is`cat()` ***without*** double quote `""`.
Surrounding character by double quote bother me, and I wanted to remove it by making `foo()`

```
> foo(aaa)
aaa
```

which is same as `cat("aaa")`.

But, R CMD check thinks the ***pseudo*** object `aaa`  does not exist.

I want to remove this note. In past, such note did not appear. But today it appears.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`globalVariables`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/globalVariables.html):

```
globalVariables('foo')
```

It’s … not a great solution — in particular, you have to do this for *every* name you use in this way.

It’s therefore better to limit NSE in package code to the absolute necessary. Pure convenience functions such as yours need to be weighed carefully against this.

Comment: Thank you, I try it. This is quick response to say thank you.